# String to string format

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which contains numbers, and I want to show this string in this numeric format: `#,##0`
So i try to add to this string `.ToString("#,##0")` but the compiler says that

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments.

Any idea how to do that without converting this string first into `int` ?

Comment: What is the problem to convert to int ?

Comment: Cause i want to know is it possible to do that without convert first to int

Comment: The only way to do it, is by substringing the input and putting the comma yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible unless you want to process the string manually. If you try `String.Format("{0:#,##0}", "1000000")` the output is `1000000`. And to me, this makes sense. While you can say "this string contains numbers all the time", that is not a safe assumption to the language to make normally.

Your best bet is to do something like:

```
String.Format("{0:#,##0}", int.Parse(input));
```

if you're sure it will always will be a castable integer.

Answer (score 1):

When you just need to format a single number, like an integer or long. In this case, you don't need to use string.Format.You can just use the ToString virtual method. This reduces some overhead. But you can't format a string directly using ToString.

Answer (score 0):

please first convert string input to the integer and then try formatting the string. Please see the example below:

```
string test = "12345";
Console.WriteLine("{0}", int.Parse(test).ToString("#,##0"));
```